# Paging not working, Extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, paging

I made an extjs grid with a bottom toolbar to create a paging behavior, but it's not working and I don't know where is the problem, I've already done it with local data, but when i used a database it didn't work, it shows all the data at once.

Here's the code :

```
Ext.require([ 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*' ]);

Ext.onReady(function() {
var categoriesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize : 10,      
    proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: 'GridDataBase/categories.php',
           reader: {
               type: 'json',
               totalProperty: 'total',
               root: 'categories',
               idProperty: 'name'
           }            
    },
    fields : ['id','name']
});

var panelOfData = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel',{
    store : categoriesStore,
    columns : [ {
        id : 'id',
        header : "Id",
        width : 20,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex : 'id'
    }, {
        id : 'name',
        header : "Category Name",
        width : 75,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex : 'name'
    } ],
    //stripeRows : true,

        //paging bar on the bottom
    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: categoriesStore,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No categories to display"
    }),
    autoExpandColumn : 'name',
    height : 350,
    width : 600,
    renderTo : 'grid-ex',
    title : 'Categories'
});

categoriesStore.loadPage(1);
console.log(categoriesStore.count()); // the log here shows 0
});
```

Here's the PHP file :

```
function GetCategories() {
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM categorie";  
    $categories = array("categories" => array());
    @mysql_connect("localhost","superuser","SS4") or die();
    mysql_select_db("dbz"); !mysql_error () or die();
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $categories["categories"][$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    return json_encode($categories);
}
echo GetCategories();
```

Comment: Have you implemented paging in `categories.php`? What paging does is passing paging related parameters to your php script, but implementation on server side is in your hands.

Comment: The page only provides a json output, the data is from mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Extjs code sends some additional params for implementing the paging on server start, limit and these params have to be used in your query to send back records upto the pagesize limit of store. Server response should also send back a property with total number of records (to be assigned to totalProperty of store) which will be used to calculate number of pages.

```
    store.load({
        params:{
            start:0,
            limit: itemsPerPage
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I don't know where i should put your code, i have to implement a handler in the toolbar, which will contain the code you provided ?

Comment: While loading the store, you have to pass the start and limit parameter values and then your query should return records equal to limit param value from start. Initially start will be 0 and limit is how many records you want to display (e.g. 20). So, now your query should first 20 records i.e. 0-19. Similarly on next page value of start param will be 20 and limit param will remain 20. Now your query should return 20 records i.e. 20-39 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You havent implemented paging on server side. Try this:

```
function GetCategories($start, $limit) {
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM categorie LIMIT $start, $limit";  
    $categories = array("categories" => array());
    @mysql_connect("localhost","superuser","SS4") or die();
    mysql_select_db("dbz"); !mysql_error () or die();
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $categories["categories"][$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    return json_encode($categories);
}
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
$limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : 0;

echo GetCategories($start, $limit);
```